# SQL Count If Date is Between 2 Dates AND Count If Not between 2 Dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

Does anyone know a way with Access VBA SQL to do a multiple count function on dates inbetween?

For Example, a Table of Dates:

```
01/16/2014  +1 To Inbetween Dates
01/17/2014 +1 to Inbetween Dates
01/13/2014 +1 to Inbetween Dates
01/01/2014 +1 to Not Inbetween Dates
01/02/2014 +1 to not inbetween dates



Start Date | End Date
01/13/2014 | 01/18/2014
```

End result should be
No. Inbetween = 3
No. Not Inbetween = 2

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you try phrasing the question better?  Sample data and expected results, along with table layouts, can really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT  SUM(IIF([Date] BETWEEN [Enter Start Date] AND [Enter End Date], 1, 0)) AS BetweenDates,
        SUM(IIF([Date] BETWEEN [Enter Start Date] AND [Enter End Date], 0, 1)) AS NotBetweenDates
FROM    T;
```

Then when running your query you would be prompted for start and end dates.

If you wanted to just hard code your dates it would look something like:

```
SELECT  SUM(IIF([Date] BETWEEN #2014-01-13# AND #2014-01-18#, 1, 0)) AS BetweenDates,
        SUM(IIF([Date] BETWEEN #2014-01-13# AND #2014-01-18#, 0, 1)) AS NotBetweenDates
FROM    T;
```

---

**EDIT (in response to comment)**

I haven't worked with access in years, and also haven't worked with anything over a few hundred rows, for anything larger I have always looked to SQL Server so can't say how normal this is. 
But you are selecting all results so a full table scan is required however you do it, the only way I can think that this may perform better is if you add an index to the date field and either do:

```
SELECT  'Between Dates' AS Status,
        COUNT(*) AS Records
FROM    T
WHERE   [Date] BETWEEN #2014-01-13# AND #2014-01-18#
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Not Between Dates' AS Status,
        COUNT(*) AS Records
FROM    T
WHERE   [Date] NOT BETWEEN #2014-01-13# AND #2014-01-18#;
```

Or:

```
SELECT  IIF([Date] BETWEEN #2014-01-13# AND #2014-01-18#, 'Between', 'Not Between') AS Status,
        COUNT(*) AS Records
FROM    T
GROUP BY IIF([Date] BETWEEN #2014-01-13# AND #2014-01-18#, 'Between', 'Not Between');
```

But with no data to test with I can't say for sure if this will help or not.

Comment: Holy crap. I have ~70k records and this query looks like it's going to take a while! Is that normal? I'm guessing checking between the dates is pretty harsh.

Comment: Woops... I had ~20k+ Blank records in the Start/End Date table... that might be why it was going so slow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general idea for that sort of query.  You can work out the details

```
select sum(case when some condition is met then 1 else 0 end) conditionsmet
, sum(case when that condition isnot  met then 1 else 0 end) conditionsnotmet
```

Comment: SQL is a generic term, the particular type required is MS Access. MS Access does not include CASE.

Comment: Tried it with Switch like this but it didn't work:

Select SUM(SWITCH([DateOfHours] Between tblBusyDates.[StartDate] AND tblBusyDates.[EndDate],1,0))